# What is the type of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I need to declare the following variable in a class:

```
auto gameStartClock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

However, I receive this error message from `gcc 5.1.0` (with C++11 enabled) whenever I try to do that:

```
<file>.hpp:274: error: non-static data member declared 'auto'
auto gameStartClock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();                                                               ^
non-static data member declared 'auto'
```

So I guess the error will be gone after I replace `auto` by the correct type. However, every example I found out there about `::now()` uses `auto`.

What is its type?

**Note:** I tried `std::chrono::time_point` with a few templates but got no success. Not sure which are the correct ones.

Comment: Okay, I see the error. I used `std::chrono::time_point`instead of `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point `. It would be more helpful to point me to it instead of throwing more documentation into the air.

Comment: I read the documentation (in cppreference wiki), but I just missed the `high_resolution_clock` namespace somehow. Should I delete the question? It wasn't asked before, I'll let people decide this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The type is `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>`.

From the manual: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now

**Edit:** As pointed out by Lightness Races in Orbit in the comments, you can also use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`

Comment: They are the same, `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` is just a typedef for `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>`